# Wie kann man optimal drei Tempora in einen Satz verschmelzen?

Tags: grammar, tense

Wieder mit einem grammatischen Distributivgesetzproblem. Wie kann man optimal gleichzeitig die folgende drei Sätze in einen Satz umwandeln?

> 1. Ich bin unterwegs gewesen.
> 2. Ich bin unterwegs.
> 3. Ich werde unterwegs sein.

**Bemerkung**: Ich bin mir fast sicher, dass es quasi eine »adverbiale« Lösung dafür gibt. Für die interessiere ich mich auch. Jedoch würde ich halt gerne wissen, ob –und ggf. wie– die drei Tempora in einen Satz verschmolzen werden können.

Ich versuche es mal mit:

> Ich bin unterwegs gewesen, bin unterwegs und werde unterwegs sein.

wobei es meines Erachtens zu viele »unterwegs« gibt. Wäre dieser Satz richtig, könnte man ein paar »unterwegs« wegwerfen? Oder ein »bin«?

Comment: Du meinst sicherlich Distributivgesetzproblem, statt Assoziativgesetzproblem.

Comment: @Toscho natürlich, danke; habe ich schon korrigiert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options and your own is not the worst one. It is not as repetitive as it seems because the *unterwegs* has a different weight in present (last position of the partial sentence) while for the other two the final position is occupied by a verb... and since it is not the same verb, the sentence sound fine all together. Think of it as a kind of rhyme. A lot is the same but the punch isn't and that gives it some appeal. Anyway, here some more  alternatives.

> Unterwegs war ich, bin ich, und werde ich sein.
>
> Ich bin unterwegs, war es bisher, und werde es weiter sein.
>
> Unterwegs - Ich war es, bin es und werde es sein.

Sorry, dass ich in Englisch geschrieben habe. Ich habe zu spät gesehen, dass du in Deutsch gefragt hast und jetzt will ich es nicht nochmal löschen.

Comment: Du hast das Perfekt zum Präteritum geändert, das ist ja quasi Cheaten.

Comment: @Toscho... ja stimmt vielleicht :)... aber für "sein" kann man das glaub ' ich machen ohne die Bedeutung zu ändern

Comment: Das kannstu du auch mit jedem anderen Verb machen. Heutzutage gibt es keinen Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen Präteritum und Perfekt mehr.

Answer (score 4):

Ein erster Versuch (wenn auch mit unlauteren Mitteln in Form des Verbs *bleiben*):

> Ich war, bin und bleibe unterwegs.

Mit „unterwegs bleiben“ bin ich aber selber nicht glücklich…

Comment: Warum eigentlich nicht... ich find das bleiben gut dort.

Comment: @Emanuel: "Bleiben" verbinde ich eher mit statischen Zuständen ("Hier ist es schön, hier bleibe ich") oder im Sinne von "eine Aktivität beibehalten" - z.B. "in Bewegung bleiben". Dagegen klingt "unterwegs bleiben" in meinen Ohren etwas sperrig.

Answer (score 2):

Erster Vorschlag, der allerdings nicht eindeutig ist. Danach wurde aber auch nicht gefragt:

> Ich bin gewesen, bin und werde unterwegs sein.

Zweiter Vorschlag unter Einführung eines `es` als Platzhalter für `unterwegs`:

> Ich bin unterwegs gewesen, bin es und werde es sein.

Dritter Vorschlag, der das erste `es` weglässt:

> Ich bin unterwegs gewesen, bin und werde es sein.

Vierter Vorschlag (auf Emanuels Antwort basierend):

> Unterwegs bin ich gewesen, bin ich und werde ich sein.